# Get upcomming services dates from today in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building a SaaS application, where product last service date and next service mode (weekly, monthly, quarterly) was stored in database, from that i need future service dates for one year from the current date in a json format as response in nodejs.

the below formated json is the structure of date stored in database,

```
[{
"ItemName":"Fan",
"LastService":"01-03-2022",
"ServiceMode":"Monthly",
},
{
"ItemName":"AC",
"LastService":"01-04-2022",
"ServiceMode":"Quarterly",
}]
```

i need the output summary response from node is in the below json format, when i send current month as request payload..

```
[{
"ItemName":"Fan",
"ServiceMode":"Monthly",
"NextServices":["01-10-2022","01-11-2022","01-12-2022","01-01-2023","01-02-2023","01-03-2023","01-04-2023",
"01-05-2023","01-06-2023","01-06-2023","01-07-2023","01-08-2023","01-09-2023",],
},
{
"ItemName":"AC",
"ServiceMode":"Quarterly",
"NextServices":["01-07-2022","01-10-2022","01-01-2023","01-04-2023"],
}]
```

Technology
Node.js, Mongo, Express

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [
    {
        ItemName: "Fan",
        LastService: "01-03-2022",
        ServiceMode: "Monthly"
    },
    {
        ItemName: "AC",
        LastService: "03-04-2022",
        ServiceMode: "Quarterly"
    }
];

let months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']


for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let checkMonth = (new Date(data[i].LastService)).getMonth();
    // console.log({checkMonth})

    if (data[i].ServiceMode === "Monthly") {
        let NextServices = [];
        let curYearMonths = months.slice(checkMonth + 1);
        let nextYearmonths = months.slice(0, checkMonth + 1);
        curYearMonths.forEach(item => {
            let validMonth = ('' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1)).length > 1 ? months.indexOf(item) + 1 : '0' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1);
            NextServices.push(validMonth + data[i].LastService.slice(2));
        });
        nextYearmonths.forEach(item => {
            let lastIndexLength = data[i].LastService.length;
            let validMonth = ('' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1)).length > 1 ? months.indexOf(item) + 1 : '0' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1);
            let validYear = data[i].LastService.slice(0, lastIndexLength - 1) + (parseInt(data[i].LastService.slice(-1)) + 1);
            console.log(validYear)
            NextServices.push(validMonth + validYear.slice(2));
        })
        data[i].NextServices = NextServices;
    } else {
        let NextServices = [];
        let curYearMonths = months.slice(checkMonth + 1).filter((item, index) => index % 3 == 0);
        curYearMonths.forEach(item => {
            let validMonth = ('' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1)).length > 1 ? months.indexOf(item) + 1 : '0' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1);
            NextServices.push(validMonth + data[i].LastService.slice(2));
        });
        let nextYearmonths = [...months.slice(checkMonth + 1), ...months.slice(0, checkMonth + 1)].filter((item, index) => index % 3 == 0);
        nextYearmonths = nextYearmonths.filter(item => !curYearMonths.includes(item));
        nextYearmonths.forEach(item => {
            let lastIndexLength = data[i].LastService.length;
            let validMonth = ('' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1)).length > 1 ? months.indexOf(item) + 1 : '0' + (months.indexOf(item) + 1);
            let validYear = data[i].LastService.slice(0, lastIndexLength - 1) + (parseInt(data[i].LastService.slice(-1)) + 1);
            NextServices.push(validMonth + validYear.slice(2));
        })
        data[i].NextServices = NextServices;
    }
};

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, but i want the output nextservices for one year from the current date.

Comment: @Prasanth plz check the above code once again i have modified the changes as per ur requirement plz let me know if u need anything else.